# How to break the result of a command over multiple pages

Tags: biblatex, macros, bibliographies, templates, cv

I am using the following template to build an academic CV:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/minimal-academic-cv-template/dztfsxjnjvhy

However, I have encountered a problem using the command that prints the publications.
The list of publications is long enough to occupy more than a single page, but the whole bibliography is printed on a single page, going beyond the margins of the page. How can I force the result of this command to break over multiple pages?

The command can be found in *fields-cv/labeled-items.tex* and it is the following:

```
\newcommand*\CVKeywordReferences[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{cvkeyrefs}{#1}
  \color{bodytxt}
  \rightminipageonly{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\descleftmargin\textwidth}%
    \labeltext%
  \end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\descrightmargin\textwidth}%
    \nocite{*}%
    \foreach \kw in \keyword {%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
        \vspace*{-0.7\baselineskip}
        \printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ynt, keyword=\keyword]
    }\x 
    }
  \end{minipage}%
  }
}
```

Comment: you have \begin{minipage}[t]{...  you can not break a minipage over a page

Comment: I already modified the command to remove all the unnecessary minipages. However, I cannot get rid of \rightminipageonly{... which is causing my problem. Do you see any workaround?

Comment: paracol comes to mind, assuming \labeltext is long enough to justfify a separate column.